# Are the corrupted Númenóreans trapped in Valinor technically alive?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, numenor

Ar-Pharazôn the Golden, the last Vala-hating king of Númenor, led an army to conquer Valinor, but Ilúvatar trapped them in a cave-in where they will remain until the end of time — the Caves of the Forgotten.

In their current status, are they technically alive, and thus necessarily the only immortal and longest living humans around?

Comment: Are the Caves of the Forgotten cited in the published Silmarillion, or in an older version of the Akallabeth in the Lost Tales / Unfinished Tales / other books? (admittedly it has been a while since last rereading, but I don't remember that name)

Comment: There was the analogous Army of the Dead from _LOTR_. They were dead, but still came back to fight at Pelennor Fields to atone for their (somewhat less greivous) sin.

Comment: The Army of the Dead crossed Gondor with Aragorn et al, fought at Pelargir, then were released from their oath.

Comment: Amandil, High King Elendil's father, also reached Valinor and would be even older as he reached Valinor just before the Great Armament.

Answer (score 4):

Questions about humans who are waiting, in some sense alive, until the Battle of Battles are unlikely to have definitive answers.  Christopher Tolkien did not include Mandos' prophecy regarding the Dagor Dagorath in the published *Silmarillion*, because his father's thoughts about the battle had changed significantly over the years.  One of the major issues with the prophecy was the role of Túrin, who, in early versions of the legendarium, had become immortal and would be Morgoth's final slayer.  Yet this was not consistent with Tolkien's eventual view of the Gift of Men.  There would be similar issues with the surviving invaders from Númenor.

Of course, we know from *The Lord of the Rings* that it is within the power of the Ainur to keep men "alive" beyond the natural span of their years, as Sauron did with the Ringwraiths.  However, their total "life" had to be stretched out over a longer and longer period, robbing them of their human characters.  If the armies of Númenor were kept alive in the cave, they might similarly have become worn out remnants of their former selves; or they might have been held in suspended animation, waiting to awaken for the end of days.

Comment: It's not necessarily inconsistent with the Gift of Men. Immortal souls may not leave Eä, while mortal soles will, but it doesn't specify *when*.

Comment: @OrangeDog Just nitpicking, but both elves' and men's souls are *immortal*, otherwise they would not survive the body's death :-)

Comment: @Ifurini that's not Tolkein's definition of mortal.

Comment: @OrangeDog Of course men are defined as *mortal* (*"... Nine for the mortal men doomed to die ..."*); I was just saying (half-jokingly) that the expression "mortal soul" seems an oxymoron.

Answer (score 1):

Ar-Pharazôn, the Golden and his army of Númenóreans were not alive as other mortal men but Tolkien did not throw light upon this matter. Either they were buried or put to sleep by Ilúvatar, it is not known till they atone for the sins and fight in the Dagor Dagorath. They are not the oldest of men if Tuor isn't alive, remember Tuor was the only mortal man who was counted among elves. So if he would have been alive which is not known than he would have been the oldest of his race.